# Spawning at wrong places godot

Tags: godot

```
func spawnCircle(): #Spawn circle at random position every 3 seconds
    var circle = TextureButton.new()
    var texture = load("res://Assets/Circle.png")
    circle.set_normal_texture(texture)
    circleSpawnTimer.start(2.5)  #spawn next circle
    randomize()
    add_child(circle)
    circle.rect_position.x = randi() % int(rect_size.x)
    circle.rect_position.y = randi() % int(rect_size.y)
    circle.connect("pressed", self, "on_Circle_pressed", [circle]) #connect circle pressed signal and pass in its reference
    var circleDisappearTimer = Timer.new()  #Timer for circles to disappear if left unclicked
    circle.add_child(circleDisappearTimer)
    circleDisappearTimer.connect("timeout", circle, "queue_free") #delete circle on timeout
    circleDisappearTimer.start(4) #After 5seconds left unclicked , the circle will disappear
```

I have a circle clicker game, everything seems to be working correctly except that the circles sometimes spawn at the edge of the screen, making it only half-visible or only a a quarter of it visible. How do I make it so the circle only spawn at places that allows it to be fully visible?

Comment: Suggestion: Make the circle, with its textures, and its timer, and signal connections… Into a new scene. Then instantiate that scene instead of doing all the work in code (see [Instancing scenes](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/scripting_continued.html#instancing-scenes)). You might even connect its `tree_entered` to a script that positions it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that [`rect_position`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_control.html#class-control-property-rect-position) corresponds to the rectangle top-left corner. And the size of the [`Control`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_control.html) ([`TextureButton`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_texturebutton.html) in this case) is [`rect_size`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_control.html#class-control-property-rect-size)…

It wil be out of bounds if the `rect_position` of the `Control` is closer to the bottom than its vertical size (`rect_size.y`), or it is closer to the right than its horizontal size (`rect_size.x`).

Thus, we need a range that goes from 0 to the size of the screen minus the size of the control.

Following the way you are using the random number generator, that would be:

```
circle.rect_position.x = randi() % int(rect_size.x - circle.rect_size.x)
circle.rect_position.y = randi() % int(rect_size.y - circle.rect_size.y)
```